# two different batches of SQL rows added in one array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am having a function that fetches information from two different tables of my SQL database.

Table one and the fetched infos are pretty much profile information for 10 users including the following information: id, nickname, age

Fetched infos from the second table are basically also 10 infos but only: id and activity.

How do I return one variable, that has BOTH information in one array and how can I retrieve the specific informations such as "getting the username of id=2" from the first fetching AND "getting the activity of the second table of id=2 as well"?

I am getting confused with larger informations (10 batches of SQL rows + another 10 batches of SQL rows in one array)

**EDIT**: alright, now I can come up with some code. I have a function

```
public function fetch_matches($user_id){
  MySQL yada yada
  $firstfetch[]=each row of sql with a foreach loop
  return array($firstfetch, $secondfetch);
}
```

I will merge two arrays in one array and return it to returning_fetches as the array $db_fetches (look below):

```
public function returning_fetches($db_fetches){
foreach ( $matches_array as $match_id) {
                        $matches[] = $this->load_user_object($match_id);
                        $newactivity[] = $this-> ????????                       
                        }
}
```

The question is in the returning_fetches function, the part where I split/access the arrays that I passed fomr the first function

```
$matches[] = $this->...????
```

The question is, how do I access the $FIRSTFETCH for $matches[] and how do I access $secondfetch for my $newactivity[] array?

Thanks so far.

If its better I can also create a new thread!

Comment: use union but you will get only id and activity. wrap the 2 in another select and use joins to get the additional info

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you have no strong id relation between the table, it's  will be impossible to fetch RIGHT set of data.

What you should have:
1  table profile :  id, nickname, age
2 table activity : id, userId, activity

in this case you can write the query

```
SELECT 
`profile`.id, 
`profile`.nickname,
`profile`.age, 
`activity`.id as activityId,
`activity`.activity  
FROM `profile`
INNER JOIN `activity` on `profile`.id = `activity`.userId
WHERE id = 2
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Alright I narrowed down my problem and made it much more specific with code attached so you can exactly see where I'm lacking the appropriate knowledge ;)

A intermediate coder would probably know in a heartbeat what do to and how to access my passed arrays there so I'm gonna leave it here hoping that someone can help a newbie out

Thanks guys